# Disk recovery for lost partition. Tools failing to load

Tags: hard-drive, partition-recovery

I've an external harddrive.

- It shows up in Device Manage
- I see drives E: and F: when plugged but no info on them. There were really two partitions before. I believe one was NTFS and second FAT32.
- Disk management (also Recuva, TrueImage, Testdisk) fails or freeze on start when disk is plugged
- Minitool Partition Wizard starts and reports the proper disk size, but says bad disk and operations are disabled.
- Partition Master shows the HDD and show partition unallocated. Can't recover partition.

Is there anything more low level I could try? Even linux tools could be favorable.

There is a 0,001% chance its the hard drive with 7500 bitcoins, I share the profit ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](http://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Answer (score 0):

To start clearing things up, you ought to find another hard disk of the same size or (better) larger, and from Linux, run a bit-by-bit copy of the damaged disk to the new disk **as a image file** using `dd`.

If it works, all well and good. If it does not, retry using `ddrescue` instead of `dd`. If it does not work, **try a professional service**.

Supposing it worked, you now have a disk image and most tools are able to work with that. **Do not use the original disk anymore** (keep it for the professional service's tender hands, if needs be).

One thing you can do to recover a Bitcoin wallet is to look for the [binary file signature](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) in the multi-gigabyte dump. It will take some time (around one hour for typical disk sizes).

For those utilities that do not support image files, you can install the appropriate OS into a VirtualBox virtual machine and connect the image file as an external drive. Now the file will be seen as a hard disk. There are utilities to do so straight in Windows (e.g. DiskMount), but verify that they allow *writing* to the virtual image disk (some are read-only).

But whatever you do, once you have a disk image you can copy it and work on the copy, and be sure that whatever you do, your chances of recovering data won't vanish.